# Rename [parcel] to [android-parcel]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parcel) has 500 questions and this tag wiki:

> In Android, a Parcel is a container for a message (data and object references). It's a high-performance alternative to Java's standard serialization.

However, there are around [238 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parcel+-android+-kotlin+-parcelable) that should instead be tagged with [parceljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parceljs), which is for a web app bundler.

Given the ambiguity of the name [parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parcel), I suggest that we rename it to [android-parcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-parcel), or another name that makes it clear that it refers to the Android concept and is unrelated to the web build tool.

Comment: [tag:parcelable] also exists and appears to have the same meaning. The tag wiki excerpt leaves something to be desired though; the full wiki is clearer that it refers to the Android functionality, and the use of the tag backs that up.

Comment: [singlespa.js](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/parcels-overview) also exists and has parcel defined as "... a framework agnostic component. It is a chunk of functionality meant to be mounted manually by an application, without having to worry about which framework was used to implement the parcel or application." It would be good to separate them out.